# Server Migration with MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager, server-migration

I'm having a little trouble figuring out the best way to migrate an install of EE with MSM.

I have 2 sites set up with MSM that are currently live. I need to switch to a new host but I obviously can't set up the new host with the existing domain names since they are already hosted elsewhere.

How do I go about setting it up on the new host?

Answer (score 1):

I've run in to this issue before. At your new host, you'll have **tempdomain.hostname.com** - this can be the primary site. For the secondary site, you may need to grab any old domain (we've used yoursiteinprogress.net) and make that the secondary domain. Update your EE config to point to these domains, and make sure everything works. Then when you're ready to flip the switch on the migration, update EE config to point to the correct domain names.